# How to add a group in MUC room XMPP - iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I want to add a group for eg VP to the chat room (XYZ Company). I am able to add a individual user to a chat room but i want to add a particular group to chat room. How can i achieve that?

I tried the following code

```
XMPPJID *userJid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",user,self.serverName]];
        [xmppRoomToInvite editRoomPrivileges:@[[XMPPRoom itemWithAffiliation:@"member" jid:userJid]]];
        [xmppRoomToInvite inviteUser:userJid withMessage:@"Welcome"];
```

But in openfire, i can see VP@servername was added as a member. But the users in the member group not receiving new chat room.

Comment: What do you call group ? Roster group ?

Comment: Yes. it is roster group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature in XMPP as default. You cannot add a roster group in a MUC room in the MUC specification. You should have your client iterate on your roster to add your needed contact from client code.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the info. I couldn't find any such feature in XMPP specification. But in openfire, i can add particular group to the chat room. Now i can able to add group through rest api (https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#add-group-with-role-to-chat-room).

Comment: i have one more query. How can i get the messages count of the chat rooms in chat list screen like in whatsapp. Should i join to all chat rooms in chat list screen to get all messages. Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: You can indeed join all chat rooms, but the best approach is probably to query MAM (Message Archive Management) archives and possibly use MUC/Sub that is found in latest ejabberd version: https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/xmpp-clients-bots/proposed-extensions/muc-sub/

Comment: Thanks Mickaël. But I am using Openfire for MAM. I am sending request as <iq type="set" id="juliet1"><query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:0"><x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="submit"><field var="FORM_TYPE" type="hidden"><value>urn:xmpp:mam:0</value></field><field var="with"><value>0fe3fddf-d3de-4332-8e44-c1d894aa7ca0@conference.myserver</value></field></x></query></iq>

and i am getting response as 
<message xmlns="jabber:client" to=“jack@myserver/iPhone”><fin xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:0"></fin></message>

But i have messages for the chat room "0fe3fddf-d3de-4332-8e44-c1d894aa7ca0".

Comment: I do not know if Openfire supports MAM for MUC.

Comment: As you pointed, i tried to use MAM, but i am getting only my messages from the room. But the scenario is that i need to get all messages of the room from the time specified. Also if another user sends a message, how can i update my chat screen that the new message is received. Should i need to query for new messages at regular interval.

Comment: If you are in the room, you do not need to query for messages, you will receive them.